# Programmatically create profile for Outlook 2016

Tags: outlook, mapi, office-2016, outlook-2016

For Outlook 2010, 2013 it was possible to programmatically create Outlook profile and set up all necessary RPC_OVER_HTTP connection settings via MAPI like in this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dvespa/archive/2013/05/21/how-to-mfcmapi-create-mapi-profile-exchange-2013.aspx.

However, looks like this approach is not working for Outlook 2016. Anybody knows is it ever possible to manually setup connection settings(or whatever else) for Outlook 2016 to create new profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation has just been posted by Dave Vespa: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dvespa/archive/2015/10/29/how-to-configure-an-outlook-2016-profile-using-mfcmapi.aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Please feel free to edit the answer to cram all the code from the blog post into a answer within the size limits of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The way MSEMS provider is configured in Outlook 2016 is different from the previous versions. From what I heard, it will be documented soon.